# Offsetting Nested Divs Vertically

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I'm currently working on a simple weather widget, but am having some trouble with positioning some of the divs. I just started CSS today (but have experience in other programming languages). It needs to be 100 pixels up, and I have no clue why it is off by so much.

.

```
   <style>
      #weather
      {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 275px;

        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        text-align: center;

        background-color: rgba(32,32,32,0.5);

        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: rgba(32,32,36,0.7);

        border-radius: 5px;
      }

      #temp
      {
        position: relative;
        width: 15%;
        height: 50;
        top: 30px;

        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        text-align: center;
      }

      #wind
      {
        position: relative;
        width: 75%;
        height: 50;
        top: 30px;

        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        text-align: center;
      }

      #desc
      {
        position: relative;
        width: 75%;
        height: 50;
        top: 30px;

        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
```

.

And here is the page where the positioning error is taking place: http://www.thenorthcoastoutpost.com/lake

Any help or tips on positioning divs/text is greatly appreciated. I've tried multiple sites with somewhat different CSS code, but none of them seem to help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which div you want where?

Comment: Temp, wind, and desc inside of the weather div. They are aligned horizontally, just vertically isn't working at all. It was aligned perfectly, but then I added in an outline to weather div and it broke.

Comment: They already align vertically. Check http://i.stack.imgur.com/zezzM.png

Comment: That's odd. It's not showing the proper text either. I'll take a screenshot a find a place to post it to show you what it looks like on my screen.

Comment: Screenshot (mobile, but still similar to how desktop appears): http://m.imgur.com/puzDVjw

Answer (score 1):

To fix this you need change a few things:

```
navigation ul{
  margin: 0;
}
navigation ul li{
  padding: 5px 1em;
}
#innerWrapper{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You could just change those attributes within the CS Elements or copy and past the CSS code above below your other CSS code.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this first thing tomorrow.

Comment: I just tried injecting it into the page (using Squarespace) and it worked instantly for the page I was editting, but the live page doesn't seem to change at all. No clue as to what is causing it.

Comment: I found the problem, but created a new one. Removing the border elements in #weather solves the problem, but I would really like to keep a border. I'll open a different question.